# How to render multiple html files in node js?

Tags: html, css, node.js, express, mariadb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O98Wy.png)

this is my server.js file.
I built the server through express and succeeded in rendering the file list.html and css, but it is impossible to move from list.html to another html file by entering localhost:8080. I want to move the write.html, edit.html, and view.html that you see over there from the list.html that I searched for localhost:8080. Please teach me the way.

I've tried many different ways of searching on Google, but I haven't got the results I want. I want to finally make a crud bulletin board and my first goal is to make it possible to move smoothly in that html form now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use routing for catching different routes/paths
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
 res.render('index.html')
})

app.get('/edit', (req, res) => {
 res.render('edit.html')
})

app.get('/view', (req, res) => {
 res.render('view.html')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `express.static('public')`, which will serve all static assets (including `html` files) in the `public folder`. Try putting the files in the `view` folder, and the `index.html`, in the `public` folder.